# Sorting NSDocumentDirectory by name

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, nssortdescriptor, nsdocumentdirectory

I want to sort all NSDocumentDirectory by fileName but folders should be first by name and then all files are sorted by name.

In my Document Directory, i have lots of files and folders also.

i have the array like,

```
_filePathsArray =[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:_selectedPath error:Nil];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code helps me... And thanks friends for your reply.

```
NSArray *fileArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:_selectedPath error:Nil];

_filePathsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *fileArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<[fileArray count];i++)
{
    if ([[[fileArray objectAtIndex:i] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [_filePathsArray addObject:[fileArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else
    {
        [fileArray1 addObject:[fileArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

}

[_filePathsArray addObjectsFromArray:fileArray1];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can sort array by alphabetically by following way. i am not sure about folders comes first.

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

OR

```
sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: thanks buddy, i know that we can sort an array using that but my issue is that in sorted list, folders should comes first. By the way thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
 [yourArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

For NSArray try this.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"interest"  ascending:YES];
[stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
recent = [stories copy];
```

Comment: its only for NSMutableArray, i want to sort NSArray and in it folder should comes first. And i dont want type cast for that.

Comment: And please post the proper code way you are fetching data from nsdocumentdirectory and handling data.

Comment: hello, in my question, there is one line, in it i got all documents data in _filesPathArray and i want to sort that array.